# How do I ensure that my x and y lengths don't differ when plotting a glm using the predict() function in R?

Tags: r, plot, glm

I am running the following code:

```
c.model<-glm(cars$speed~cars$dist, family=gaussian)
summary(c.model)
c.x<-seq(0,1,0.01)
c.x
c.y<-predict.glm(c.model,as.data.frame(c.x), type="response")
c.y
plot(cars$dist)
lines(c.x,c.y)
```

And getting the error, "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ". I'm not quite sure what is causing this error.

Comment: You're getting the error because `length(c.x) = 101` and `length(c.y) = 50`.

Comment: `c.y <- predict.glm(...)` should have given you the following helpful hint - `Warning message:
'newdata' had 101 rows but variables found have 50 rows `

Comment: So, I suppose my question then distills to, "how to I get the predict() function to produce as many values as the sequence I fed it?".

Comment: You would be advised to start using the `data` argument for regression functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be more careful in matching up the variable names used in the model, and those used during prediction. The error you are getting is because the names in the data.frame in the preidct function do not match the names of the terms in your model so you're not actually predicting new values. The problem is that `predict` is essentially getting the data from

```
model.frame(~cars$dist, data.frame(dist=c.x))
```

so because you explicitly have `cars$dist` in your formula, there are no "free" symbols that will be taken from your newdata parameter. Compare that to the results from

```
model.frame(~dist, data.frame(dist=c.x))
```

This time, `dist` isn't specifically tied to the the `cars` variable and can be "resolved" in the context of the newdata data.frame.

Additionally, you want to make sure you're keeping your dist values on the same scale. For example.

```
c.model <- glm(speed~dist, data=cars, family=gaussian)
summary(c.model)
c.x <- seq(min(cars$dist),max(cars$dist),length.out=101)
c.y <- predict.glm(c.model,data.frame(dist=c.x), type="response")
plot(speed~dist, cars)
lines(c.x,c.y)
```

[image]

Here we predict over the range of observed values rather than 0-1 because no distance value is actually less than 1.

Comment: could you clarify a little more what you meant by, " The error you are getting is because the names in the data.frame in the preidct function do not match the names of the terms in your model so you're not actually predicting new values,"? Your change works beautifully, but I can't say I fully appreciate why. Thank you, btw.

Comment: @Atticus29 I've updated to try to include more details. Basically, you should never use `$` in combination with `~` (* some exceptions may exist but it's generally true).